# With SQL Server XML data type, how to update the value attribute when searching with another attribute to locate the xml node?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xmldocument

I have a XML column in my table that stores a XML structure like this:

```
<cars>
    <car name="Ford" value="123" />
    <car name="Honda" value="456" />
</cars>
```

I want to modify all rows that have name="Honda" and value="456". I need to update  the number 456 to 789.

I tried this:

```
UPDATE cars
SET XmlData.modify('replace value of (/cars/car[@name="Honda"]/value) with "789"')
WHERE isProcessed = 0
```

I am getting the error:

> Msg 2261, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
>   XQuery Cars.XmlData.modify()]: There is no element named 'value' in the type 'element(car,#anonymous) *'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were so close...  Just missed  `.../@value)[1]`

**Example**

```
Declare @Cars table (ID int,IsProcessed bit,XMLData xml)
Insert Into @Cars values
(1,0,'<cars><car name="Ford" value="123" /><car name="Honda" value="456" /></cars>')

Update @Cars
 Set   XMLData.modify('replace value of (/cars/car[@name="Honda"]/@value)[1]  with "789"')
 WHERE isProcessed = 0

Select * from @Cars
```

**The Updated XML**

```
<cars>
  <car name="Ford" value="123" />
  <car name="Honda" value="789" />
</cars>
```